# Docker command to fetch dockerfile from registry

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm new to docker and I wonder why there is no command to fetch `AUTOMATED BUILD`-repo's Dockerfile to build image locally from it (can be convenient some times I guess, instead of opening browser, peeking for github reference on repo's page and then using git to clone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created `dockerfileview` to fetch Dockerfile from Docker Hub.

https://github.com/remore/dockerfileview

Answer (score 0):

The automated build normally has a githubrepo behind it and links to the original repository in the build details section under the Source Repository heading. Which automated build are you looking for the source file for?

[image: BuildDetails]

If you would like to search for images from the command line you can run `docker search TERM` to find images (but not their docker files). You can also use `docker history` to give a rough approximation of the commands that went in the docker file.

e.g.

Comment: I was wondering if there is method to see githubrepo of image from cli.

Comment: If its already an automated build why would you need to rebuild it? You can just pull.

Comment: I need to audit, tune, and learn the build before running it on my computer.